# javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-servicemix

I have different problems with a Camel Producer that I tried to solved but I've fallen into other problems.

1) The first implementation I did was to create a producer template each time we needed to communicate with an ActiveMQ topic. That resulted with poor memory results leading to server crashing after sometime.

The solution for the memory problem was to stop() producer template after each request. That fix has corrected the memory issue but cause some latency problem.

2) I read somewhere that it's not necessary to create each time a producer template. So I decide to fix the latency problem and declared only one producer template in my class and use it for each request. It seem to work fine, no memory leak, fix the latency problem...

BUT, when we send multiple queries that take a lot of time (20 sec each), it looks like we hit a timeout and the component crash with something like «***javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed***».

**Is there a way to do multi threading? Is this cause by using InOut exchange pattern? How the MAXIMUM_CACHE_POOL_SIZE works? Is my implementation is right?**

I've put a sample of the code of my component:

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception 
{        
    Message in = exchange.getIn(); 

    if (producerTemplate == null) {            
        CamelContext camelContext = exchange.getContext();
        //camelContext.getProperties().put(Exchange.MAXIMUM_CACHE_POOL_SIZE, "50");
        producerTemplate = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
    }

    ...
    result = producerTemplate.sendBody(String.format("activemq:%s", camelContext.resolvePropertyPlaceholders("{{channel1}}")), ExchangePattern.InOut, messageToSend).toString(); 

    ...
    finalResult = producerTemplate.sendBody(String.format("activemq:%s", camelContext.resolvePropertyPlaceholders("{{channel2}}")), ExchangePattern.InOut, result).toString(); 

    ...
    in.setBody(finalResult );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is because you use InOut pattern.
Your route expects a response to the specified reply queue, which is never received, and therefore results in the default 20 sec. timeout.

Change the Exchange pattern to InOnly to resolve your issue.

Apart from that, your posted code seems to be fine.
The MAXIMUM_CACHE_POOL_SIZE is used internally in Camel, and thus does not effect the ActiveMQ endpoint settings.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I use InOut pattern because this producer respond to a REST query. I don't think I can change that for InOnly...

Comment: The producer template creates a new Exchange, so you don't have to change the exchange pattern of the original Exchange on the route to the processor that you have supplied. You can use InOnly just for the Exchanges created in your processor.

Comment: Hmmm not sure to understand. How it can work with InOnly pattern if I have to wait for a response?

Comment: Sorry, then I'm noy sure that I understand the problem. Are you expecting to get a responses to these messages? If so, then you need to define a reply queue and use InOut pattern.

Comment: Yes I am waiting a response when I call sendBody. It works fine. But sometime, I get timeout because the processing take 20-30 sec. Could you show me a sample of how I can use InOut pattern with a reply queue?

Comment: OK, but if the integration partner will take more than the default 20 sec to reply, then you will receive a timeout. Setting reply queue explicit is esay, just set "replyTo" header on endpoint see: http://camel.apache.org/jms.html